# Css not loading on mobile browsers

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

I had a website hacked a while back and I've been cleaning out the server, changing / updating things, changing passwords etc and one of the things i cant figure out is, why when this website (http://prestigesolar.net/) is viewed on a mobile,  the site loads but no style or images come through.

I've checked the header areas of the site for possible mobile stylesheets, .htaccess files, css files themselves for possible @meta screen code or @import etc....hoping id find maybe a bad/hacked path or...or ***anything*** to give me a clue, but overall I've mostly found nothing or corrected/removed weird paths etc.

After all this, the site started behaving semi normal but then when viewing the site on a mobile, i would get redirected to a porn site. I kept looking and found other .htaccess files
that when i put onto my system to edit gave me massive trojan warnings etc. I've since removed them all and placed a normal lean one.

Now the site itself is fixed (at least for now) but, when viewing the site on a mobile, it now displays only text.

As far as the website is concerned, its a wordpress based website, standard win server. normal plugins etc and is based on the WP 2010 default theme.

Any ideas as to other things i can look at to correct this issue?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you should not be loading css via http

Comment: Well the paths are being generated via the <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> function. not sure whats going on

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` section when you call CSS try instead `media="all"` to put `media="screen"`.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your response. i changed it as you suggested and still no good.

Comment: Same thing as @somdow

Comment: Not sure what this comment is about @Euloiix, but this post is no longer valid, i had to recode everything so this problem isnt live anymore.

Comment: I resolved it eventually. 

For me, it was due to `localhost` being hardcoded in the `Settings` interface of WordPress. So when I was accessng my website from another laptop/mobile, no CSS/images were found. 
Entering the IP address instead of `localhost` solved it.