# Wordpress does not load css and image files

Tags: wordpress, configuration, content-management-system

I have installed  wordpress on a host but when i am trying to acess the website from another host or mobile device - it loads but does not load the css and image files.
I found the following post here in the forum:

[Css not loading on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787090/css-not-loading-on-mobile-browsers/40629396?noredirect=1#comment68491587_40629396)

But unfortunately they did not specified in which file they changed the localhost to the IP. I have tried to digging into the most of the wordpress files but i got totally lost.
When i access the pages from the host on which wordpress is installed everything working fine i can see the css and images so there should be a missconfiguration somewhere on the settings.
I really appreciate your help guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please give me url of your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of it someone changed the default address resolution in the settings section of wordpress.

Go into WP Admin > Settings > Site address and WP address. See what's listed there.

Referenced screenshots can be found here

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it :)))) It was so easy in the settings section in the admin panel, at first I thought that i need to dig into some of the files which are in the wordpress directory. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: Most welcome! Please do mark the response as answered when you have a moment.